# List out admin user id who add the product in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, products

I have created **user1 and user2** only to add the product and I want to show there ID in a new column I want to add new column in `catlog/Manage` Product  before name column.

Comment: Please share, what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach:

1. I have created a table where a will save the admin user id and the product that has been saved by this admin. In this table i have created a FK on product_id with `catalog_product_entity` on `entity_id`, product_id that is saved under this table is unique.
2. On `catalog_product_save_after` event I have checked that current product is saved in my database. If it is, I just call `return`, else(means that is created a new product) I save the admin user id and product id in my database.
3. When you enter in product grid you will see the admin_id for each product.

if something is unclear, feel free to ask

Resources:

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/event-driven-architecture-in-magento-observer-pattern/

https://www.atwix.com/magento/thumbnail-images-admin-product-grid/

```
app/etc/modules/Namespace_AdminId.xml
```

will contain

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_AdminId>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_AdminId>
    </modules>
</config>
```

next

```
app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php
```

with

```
<?php 
class Namespace_AdminId_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('admin_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('AdminId'),
            'align' => 'left',
            'index' => 'admin_id',
            'width'     => '70',
            'renderer' => 'Namespace_AdminId_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_AdminId'
        )); 
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

next

```
app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/Block/Adminhtml/Template/Grid/Renderer/AdminId.php
```

with

```
<?php 
class Namespace_AdminId_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_AdminId extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return $this->_getValue($row);
    } 
    protected function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
    {       
        $userAdminId = Mage::getModel('namespace_adminid/savedby')->load($row->getId())->getAdminId();
        return $userAdminId;
    }
}
```

next

```
app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/Model/Savedby.php
```

with

```
<?php

class Namespace_AdminId_Model_Savedby extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace_adminid/savedby');
    }
}
```

next

```
app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/Model/Resource/Savedby.php
```

with

```
<?php

class Namespace_AdminId_Model_Resource_Savedby extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace_adminid/savedby', 'savedby_id');
    }
}
```

next

```
app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/Model/Resource/Savedby/Collection.php
```

with

```
<?php
class Namespace_AdminId_Model_Resource_Savedby_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace_adminid/savedby');
    }
}
```

next is observer

```
app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/Model/Observer.php
```

with

```
<?php
class Namespace_AdminId_Model_Observer
{
     public function addProductSaver($observer)
     {
        $productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session'); 
        $userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();
        $saveByModel = Mage::getModel('namespace_adminid/savedby');
        $collection = $saveByModel->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('admin_id', array('eq' => $userId))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productId));

        if(count($collection)){
            return;
        }
        else{
            $data = array('admin_id' => $userId, 'product_id' => $productId);
            $saveByModel->addData($data);
            try {
                $saveByModel->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

next install script

```
app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/sql/namespace_adminid_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php
```

with

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('namespace_adminid/savedby'))
    ->addColumn('savedby_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('admin_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Admin Id')
    ->addColumn('product_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Product_Id')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('namespace_adminid/savedby', array('product_id'), Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE),
        array('product_id'), array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE)
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('namespace_adminid/savedby', 'product_id', 'catalog/product','entity_id'),
        'product_id',
        $installer->getTable('catalog/product'), 
        'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, 
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    ); 
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

and...

```
app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/etc/config.xml
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_AdminId>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_AdminId>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
         <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <addproductsaver>
                        <class>Namespace_AdminId_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addProductSaver</method>
                    </addproductsaver>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events> 
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_grid>Namespace_AdminId_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <namespace_adminid>
                <class>Namespace_AdminId_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>namespace_adminid_resource</resourceModel>
            </namespace_adminid>
            <namespace_adminid_resource>
                <class>Namespace_AdminId_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <savedby>
                        <table>namespace_adminid_savedby</table>
                    </savedby>                  
                </entities>
            </namespace_adminid_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <namespace_adminid_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_AdminId</module>
                </setup>
            </namespace_adminid_setup>
            <namespace_adminid_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </namespace_adminid_read>
            <namespace_adminid_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </namespace_adminid_write>
        </resources> 

    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: should i create new table in magento database  if yes then tell me the name  of the table, and one thing  that what will be the table name

Comment: you don't need to create a table in the database...you just need to copy the code from above and everything will work. The table is created by install script 'app/code/local/Namespace/AdminId/sql/namespace_adminid_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php'

Comment: I have provided 3 links as refferences. Take a look at first link for a better understanding the concept of install script and table creation in magento

Comment: and please mark as answered if everything is working fine :D

Comment: sorry  its not working

Comment: only column added but the admin user id not  comming

Comment: so please  check it now and update again  thank for helping me

Comment: The functionality provided by my module is available for products that are saved from now. Enter on a product and save it. After that when you will enter on products grid you will see the admin id that has saved the product

Comment: I don't think that magento can provide that information(the admin id that has saved the product). So you can track admin ids starting from now, with my module.

Comment: i have add new product,on saving new product user id not   coming in the column

Comment: 1.  Make sure that the install script has been runned, check in 'core_resources' table for script 'namespace_adminid_setup'. If you don't have this script there, make sure that you have respected the exact folder structure as i have described above and try to clear the cache.  2. If the script is in the 'core_resources' table, check if you have in your database the 'namespace_adminid_savedby' table. 3. Check your log files 'system.log' for errors related to this module

Comment: your module create a table in my database with name namespace_adminid_savedby in this  there are three column saveby_id,admind_id,_product_id in this  value is going properlly and  namespace_adminid_setup also running. but the admin user id not comming in  product grid column.

Comment: save by id  is incrementing  like 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible way available for your question. Below is one of possible way.

> Step 1 : Create product attribute for Created By (create_by) using
>   setup script which will store admin id
>
> Step 2 : Rewrite/Over write
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
>   saveAction to add admin id in product OR catch event observer for
>   this.
>
> Step 3 : Rewrite/Over write
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php to join
>   and display admin name before product name

Comment: please make  a module .

Comment: @anp.wismad sorry no time :)