# See which user created a customer in backend

Tags: customer-segmentation, ce-1.9.2.4

Is there anyway to track which user creates customer accounts in the magento backend? I'm unfortunately running into a he-said/she-said situation, where customer accounts are being setup incomplete and I need to know who the culprit is.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is only available in magento EE. You would have to install a module to have this functionality in your shop.

Some extensions I found in google:

https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log.html
http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee_docs/content/system-operations/admin-actions-log.html

Also read this article could be of interest to you: http://inchoo.net/magento/logging-user-customer-actions-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt my module from this post for the customer grid

[List out admin user id who add the product in magento 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103636/list-out-admin-user-id-who-add-the-product-in-magento/103690?noredirect=1#comment141462_103690)

Good luck !