# Show only particular users products

Tags: magento-1.8, php

im new to magento, i just created a new admin user with limited roles, like: manage products, etc.
i want this user can add, delete and update his own products, i dont want this user to show anybody's products that others added through admin panel.
here is my screen shot of products that other users have added but not this user. i wanna show only his products not others.
[image]

Comment: I think you might find your answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103636/list-out-admin-user-id-who-add-the-product-in-magento-1

Comment: can u provide me the exact solution, i didn't find any useful over there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a module that saves the logged in user id to the product that is created.

Using the saved data you could improve the product grid function by adding an extra filter which checks if the product is added by the currently loggedin user.

Comment: can i have the code please.

Comment: @JayKapoor this code you can find in the link i provided before. Only you should edit this to your prefrences: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103690/52382.